# Warning: POST Content-Length of 140150966 bytes exceeds the limit of 104857600 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Tags: templates, joomla, joomla-extensions

I get the above error in joomla 3.1.5 when i attempt to install a template from extension manager. I increased the upload limit but it dint solve my problem.

Comment: did you restart Apache after increasing the limit?

Comment: yes , i did restart apache after increasing the limit

Answer (score 0):

As well as increasing the `upload_max_filesize`, you also need to increase the `post_max_size`.

Try setting the `post_max_size` to something like 20M